# Timing collections class sort and timing making an arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist, timing

This is code which I have written to time how long it takes to perform a selection sort:

```
static public String [ ] selectionSort(String [ ] wordlist)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < wordlist.length; i++) 
    {
        int s = i-1;

        for (int j = i; j < wordlist.length; j++) 
        {
            if (wordlist[j].compareTo(wordlist[s]) < 0) 
            {
                s = j;
            }
        }

     String temp = wordlist[i-1];
     wordlist[i-1] = wordlist[s];
     wordlist[s] = temp;
    }

    return wordlist;
}

static public String [ ] timedSelectionSort(String [ ] wordlist)
{
    long startTime = 0;
    long stopTime = 0;
    long elapsedMillis = 0;
    long elapsedSec = 0;
    long elapsedMin = 0;     

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    wordlist = selectionSort(wordlist);

    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedMillis = stopTime-startTime;
    elapsedSec = elapsedMillis/1000;
    elapsedMin = elapsedMillis/60000;
    System.out.printf("File reading took %d minutes and %s secs and %d milliseconds to execute\n",
                        elapsedMin,elapsedSec%60, elapsedMillis%1000);  
    System.out.println("Read " + wordlist.length + " strings.");

    return wordlist;
}
```

I have to also time a how long it takes to make an arraylist object containing all of the strings in an array (my attempt is below)

```
static public ArrayList<String> makeArrayListClassObject(String [ ] wordlist)
{
    long startTime = 0;
    long stopTime = 0;
    long elapsedMillis = 0;
    long elapsedSec = 0;
    long elapsedMin = 0;     

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordlist));

    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedMillis = stopTime-startTime;
    elapsedSec = elapsedMillis/1000;
    elapsedMin = elapsedMillis/60000;
    System.out.printf("File reading took %d minutes and %s secs and %d milliseconds to execute\n",
                        elapsedMin,elapsedSec%60, elapsedMillis%1000);  
    System.out.println("Read " + wordlist.length + " strings.");

    return stringList;
}
```

as well as time how long it takes to sort the arraylist object using the Collections.sort( ) method. I have made the method (see below) but I don't know how to time it

```
static public void collectionsClassSort(ArrayList<String> arraylist)
{
    Collections.sort(arraylist);
}
```

I guess my questions are:
1. Is there a way to use the same method to time these two methods the way I timed the first method?
2. If not, how can I time these two methods?

**EDIT**: the timed collections sort now works, but the timed building of the arraylist still does not. meaning that the timer says that the method took 0 minutes, 0 seconds, and 0 milliseconds to execute

This is the updated code for that:

```
static public ArrayList<String> makeArrayListClassObject(String [ ] wordlist)
{
    long startTime = 0;
    long stopTime = 0;
    long elapsedMillis = 0;
    long elapsedSec = 0;
    long elapsedMin = 0;     

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordlist));

    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedMillis = stopTime-startTime;
    elapsedSec = elapsedMillis/1000;
    elapsedMin = elapsedMillis/60000;
    System.out.printf("File reading took %d minutes and %s secs and %d milliseconds to execute\n",
                        elapsedMin,elapsedSec%60, elapsedMillis%1000);  

    return stringList;                  
}
```

Comment: How is this case different? What confuses you here?

Comment: I have tried to time the other methods using the same basic formula, and it has not worked.

Comment: Please describe your "*it hasn't worked*" in more detail.

Comment: please see my newest edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use something like this,

> startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
>
> Collections.sort(arraylist);
>
> stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Its samething that you used above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between "*doesn't work*" and "*doesn't produce a meaningful result*".

It seems that your `wordList` string array is not large enough to notice time difference.

Two suggestions:

1. Test it with a much bigger array: *hundreds of thousands* of words (see my test code at the bottom)
2. Use [System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) that should yield better precision (see the explanation below).

From [David Holmes' Weblog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks):

> The absolute "time-of-day" clock is represented by the
>   System.currentTimeMillis() method, that returns a millisecond
>   representation of wall-clock time in milliseconds since the epoch. As
>   such it uses the operating system's "time of day" clock. The update
>   resolution of this clock is often the same as the timer interrupt (eg.
>   10ms), but on some systems is fixed, independent of the interrupt
>   rate.
>
> The relative-time clock is represented by the System.nanoTime() method
>   that returns a "free-running" time in nanoseconds. This time is useful
>   only for comparison with other nanoTime values. The nanoTime method
>   uses the highest resolution clock available on the platform, and while
>   its return value is in nanoseconds, the update resolution is typically
>   only microseconds. However, on some systems there is no choice but to
>   use the same clock source as for currentTimeMillis() - fortunately
>   this is rare and mostly affects old Linux systems, and Windows 98.
>
> You should always try to use nanoTime to do timing measurement or
>   calculation (and yes there are JDK API's that don't do this), in the
>   hope that it will have a better resolution than currentTimeMillis.

The following code produced "`2`" on my system:

```
import java.util.*;


public class ArrayTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] wordList = new String [600000];
        for(int i=0; i<wordList.length; ++i)
            wordList[i] = "" + i;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(wordList));
        long elapsedTime =  System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(elapsedTime);

    }

}
```

Comment: Late response, but using a larger data file did in fact yield the result I was looking for. Thank you.